# Extracting Email Data

Tags: email, outlook

I am trying to pull data from Outlook mail to an Excel worksheet.

```vb
Sub ExtractOutlookEmails()
        
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookNamespace As Object
    Dim outlookFolder As Object
    Dim outlookItem As Object
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
    
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set outlookFolder = outlookNamespace.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 represents the Inbox folder
    
    For Each outlookItem In outlookFolder.Items
        If TypeOf outlookItem Is Object  And outlookItem.Class = 43 Then ' 43 represents Mail Item
            rowNumber = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ws.Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value = outlookItem.Subject
            ws.Cells(rowNumber, 2).Value = outlookItem.SenderEmailAddress
            ws.Cells(rowNumber, 3).Value = outlookItem.ReceivedTime
        End If
    Next outlookItem
    
    Set outlookItem = Nothing
    Set outlookFolder = Nothing
    Set outlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This gives

> object does not support this property or method.

on the line

```
Set outlookFolder = outlookNamespace.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outlookNamespace is already the MAPI. The error is from the repeating of the GetNamespace method.

```
    Set outlookFolder = outlookNamespace.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 represents the Inbox folder
```

remove GetNamespace("MAPI") from the command.

```
    Set outlookFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 represents the Inbox folder
```